# How i compare two objects ol.geom.Polygon?

Tags: polygon, openlayers

I have two objects ol.geom.Polygon and I need to compare if this two objects are equal. For example if this objects have the same coordinates, these objects are equal but if the coordinates are different these objects are different. I haven't any idea how I implement this, and if have some method compare two Polygons.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the coordinates of the 2 geometries in a loop or you can retirieve the geometries as WKT and compare them as strings like this :

```
var formatWKT = new ol.format.WKT();
var feature1 = formatwkt.writeGeometry(feature1.getGeometry());
var feature2 = formatwkt.writeGeometry(feature2.getGeometry());
if(feature1 == feature2){
    console.log("equal geometries");
    //----- do your stuff here
}
else{
    console.log("different geometries");
}
```

**Edit :**

After @Lars pointed out that the coordinates must be arranged first, a better approach would be to get the intersection between the two polygons using turf.js and compute it's area and check if it is 0 ( or if you choose something near 0 due to an error in the polygons )

```
var formatGeoJSON = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var intersection = formatGeoJSON.readFeature(
turf.intersect(
    formatGeoJSON.writeFeatureObject(feature1),
    formatGeoJSON.writeFeatureObject(feature2)
    )
 );
 //supposing you are using WGS84
 var sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);
 var area=Math.abs(sphere.geodesicArea(intersection.getGeometry().getLinearRing(0).getCoordinates()));
 if(area==0){//or is <= someValue
     //equal geometries
 }
```

Comment: You also might want to consider rearranging your coordinates. 2 geometries might have the same coordinates but in a different order.

Comment: @Lars yes, good point ! it totally went out of my mind